# Is there any wget command to download .jpg pictures from one docker container folder to another container?

Tags: png, jpeg, wget, docker-container, docker-image

I am new to docker and I have a task to download pictures from a docker container1 to container2 using wget and IP of container1's path.
In detail:
container1:I have downloaded some pictures from a URL into container1
container2:I have pinged and enabled the apache server and used wget to download those pictures that are there in container1, I was able to download some pictures but I found those are not the pictures that I downloaded in container1.

I am using this wget command '*wget -nd -H -p -A jpg,jpeg,png,gif -e robots=off 172.17.0.2/*'
I have my pictures in the container1 media folder. Is it possible to download using IP, if not and if there is a way to do this task, please let me know? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the command, first I created a folder pics in the root path of the conatiner1 image which happens to be my webserver container: */var/www/html/pics*
I downloaded all the pictures from a website into this folder and
from another container i.e.,
In container2 I used the command *wget -r -P /pathtodownload -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png -e robots=off IPADDRESS/pics* which downloads the pictures from container1